# Unexpected token else, not a semicolon after if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Trying to write a rock paper scissors game, using codecademy to learn. I've seen a lot of people talking about this error and it being related to using a semicolon after an if statement but I don't know if I'm completely missing something or it's something different. Here's the code, it's a little weird to understand (and least to me), but hopefully you'll see what I didn't

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {  
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: That's not hugely useful in this situation, the braces are messing me up enough as it is, since I'm very new to Javascript

Comment: It's not done yet, I need to add another statement for that, this just seems to be messing with me at the minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `}` at the end of your code (line 21) and place it on line 12 instead.

Fixed code:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {  
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, that worked, thank you! braces are really starting to mess with me with the whole if-ception type thing, so thanks a lot!

Comment: It says I need to wait a whil to do so but shall do - quick off the mark to answer and correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing brace `}` before your second `else if` statement, and you have an extra one near the end of your code.

Fixed code :

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {  
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd been told. thank you for the correction! It is working now